# Ubuntu 14.04 - How to connect to Apple's Time Capsule?

Tags: 14.04, time, apple

I have this http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z287/dguyse/IMG_0108.jpg in my living room. It's connected to my router and I connect to it (because it has greater WiFi range than my internet provider's crap of a router) to go to internet. The Time Capsule also has 2TB drive in it, so it's a nice storage location. There is Airport Utility that can be downloaded for Mac to connect to that storage and its settings. There is also an Airport Utility software for Windows that can do the same. For Linux (Ubuntu), there is no such software, at least not to my knowledge. There ARE ways to connect to it, but those methods work only for earlier Ubuntu distros.

Is there a way for me to connect to that Time Capsule's storage on Ubuntu 14.04?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you have mount.cifs

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

I had a hard time with this too until I hit on this

http://blog.martinshouse.com/2014/09/mounting-apple-time-capsule-share-from.html

In short, I added this line to my /etc/fstab file

```
//10.0.1.1/Data /media/timecapsule  cifs    password=<timecap pw>,uid=1000,sec=ntlm,user    0 0
```

10.0.1.1 is your TC IP address.  uid is your user id to set the permissions and user allows you to mount it without being root.  Then from a terminal you can "mount /media/timecapsule" and it will work.

Comment: A year later, thanks! It worked! I didn't respond earlier because I've given up on Linux at that time. Until now!

Comment: cool - glad it helped!  If you are using a graphical desktop in 15.10 you can go to File -> Connect to Server while in the file manager.  This might also work in 14.04 but I can't test that.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04, I don't believe the other methods work (Ubuntu 20.04 was released long after both the question and previous answer). I've tested this and it seems to work:

**1. Install cifs-utils**

This installs the necessary utilities to mount Common Internet File System (CIFS) volumes, like the Time Capsule.

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

**2. Create a mount point**

This is where your Time Capsule volume will be mounted and appear in your filesystem

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/timecapsule
```

**3. Mount the Time Capsule**

This actually mounts the Time Capsule to the mount point.

```
sudo mount.cifs //TIME_CAPSULE_IP/TIME_CAPSULE_NAME /media/timecapsule -o sec=ntlm,vers=1.0,uid=$USER
```

In this command you should set:

- `TIME_CAPSULE_IP` to the IP address of your Time Capsule. If you're using it as your router this is likely to be `10.0.1.1`, otherwise you can look in your router's settings for connected clients or use a network scanning tool like nmap to find this (e.g. `nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24`). If you get this wrong you are likely to get a long pause, then `mount error(2): No such file or directory`.
- `TIME_CAPSULE_NAME` to the name your Time Capsule's volume. This is likely either `Data` or of the form `Joe Bloggs Time Capsule` (using your name). You should escape spaces with backslash e.g. `//Joe\ Bloggs\ Time\ Capsule/Data`. This name may also be discovered in file browsers like Nautilius in 'Other locations'. If you get this wrong you are likely to quickly get `mount error(2): No such file or directory`.

Older instructions will omit the important `vers=1.0` parameter here (as this used to be the default). Without this you are likely to get one of these errors depending on your OS version, TC version and TC firmware version:

- Unable to access location
- Got error "kFPAuthContinue" from server
- Could not connect to Time-Capsule-Name.local: No route to host
- Failed to retrieve share list from server: No route to host
- mount error(2): No such file or directory

Similarly, without the `sec=ntlm` option newer versions default to the ntlmssp security mode. Without this you are likely to get the error:

- mount error(13): Permission denied

If you have already mounted the volume, you are likely to get the error:

- mount error(16): Device or resource busy

Without the `uid=$USER` the volume will be mounted so only the root user can modify files. Trying to edit files will likely result in permissions errors.

If you struggle to login, it's likely your password is wrong. This will result in the `mount error(13): Permission denied` message. On usernames, generally Time Capsules don't seem to verify them whatsoever and anything can be used for it. However, you can try changing the user with the `user=Joe` option.

**4. Browse files on your mounted volume**

You should now be able to browse around `/media/timecapsule` and see and edit your files

**5. Unmount the Time Capsule and remove the directory**

To close the connection and cleanup the `/media` folder, you can run:

```
sudo umount /media/timecapsule
sudo rmdir /media/timecapsule
```

Comment: ➜  ~ sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.16/epidisc /media/epinux/TC -o sec=ntlm,vers=1.0,uid=$USER
Password for root@//192.168.0.16/epidisc: 
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

Comment: Nov  9 10:32:50 epinux kernel: [127450.319206] bad security option: ntlm
Nov  9 10:32:50 epinux kernel: [127450.319206] 
Nov  9 10:32:50 epinux kernel: [127450.319213] CIFS: VFS: bad security option: ntlm

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to reply to user1013346's comment, but I wanted to add some info for Ubuntu 22.

domdomegg's answer will no longer work due to NTLM being removed from cifs -- see discussion [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215375#c10). One option is to downgrade your kernel; but what worked for me was to use a Raspberry Pi as a bridge. You could do the same with any other Linux device running an older version. The current RPi OS (Bullseye) has the same issue with NTLM being removed, but you can get still RPi Buster [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-legacy). Once you have Buster installed on a Pi, you can join your AirPort's WiFi network and mount it with:

`sudo mount -t cifs --verbose -o vers=1.0,uid=1000,gid=1000,password={password},sec=ntlm //{airport_name}/Data ~/{mount_point}`

...assuming you have a uid 1000 user on the Pi. Replace `{password}` with the AirPort's password, `{airport_name}` with its name or IP, and `{mount_point}` with some mount point you create on the Pi.

Once you've done that you can SSH to your Pi from Ubuntu 22 and access `~/{mount_point}`. You can of course also use `scp`, `rsync`, etc. to move files around, but I found it handy to open a GUI file explorer via `nautilus sftp://{pi_username}@{pi_IP}/{full_path_to_mount_point}`.

So if your Pi username is the default "pi", your pi is at 192.168.1.10, and your AirPort is mounted on the Pi at `~/airport`, the command would be `nautilus sftp://pi@192.168.1.10/home/pi/airport`; I ran into issues trying to use a truncated directory path here, so I recommend typing out the full path.