# Connecting to Apple Airport Time Capsule: Got error "kFPAuthContinue" from server

Tags: apple, cifs, nas

Trying to connect to the time capsule, I've explicitly set my username and password using a separate OSX machine.  So I know all of my credentials are correct.

For some reason though, when I try to connect through nautilus, I get the message:

```
Got error "kFPAuthContinue" from server
```

Obviously Apple is just being difficult here, but I'd love to be able to read and write files to my airport time capsule from Ubuntu computers.

Answer (score 6):

my solution was to mount the drive from the shell as root using :

```
mount //IPADDROFCAPSULE/Data /media/capsule -o username=jeff,sec=ntlm,uid=jeff
```

notes :

- username=jeff : jeff is the name setup on the account on the time capsule (using airport utility on an iphone)
- uid=jeff : jeff is my logon name in linux
- IPADDROFCAPSULE : put in your I.P. address of the capsule
- Data is the name of the drive as set in airport utility
- /media/capsule is a mount point of own choosing - make the directory first of course

I'm using Fedora, but I expect this will work the same on ubuntu, etc., if you use sudo where you cannot log in as root

Found the answer here : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2118108

They show :

```
sudo mount.cifs //IP_ADDRESS/Data ~/capsule -o password=CAPSULE_PASSWORD,sec=ntlm,uid=LOCAL_USERNAME
```

and I think this works if instead of accounts in airport utility you set a password on the drive itself. Or it's that this user had an account on the time capsule with the same name as the `LOCAL_USERNAME`.

But my line above works for me!

Comment: The important part here for me was making sure `uid` is set. you can't use `mount -a` without being sudo (i'm using `fstab`) and that's running as `root`, but I will be using the drive as my local user. Everything became writeable:  `//zerogravitas/lastingdamage /home/[user]/RemoteBackups cifs username=admin,password=[password],vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,rw,uid=[user]`

Comment: Eeek, I had to come here and add that you can also use the standard 'guest' only connection of a timecapsule by using the `guest` flag for passwordless mounting

Answer (score 1):

On later versions of Ubuntu, Samba requires you to specify you want the old version with `vers=1.0` (this previously was the default but no longer is).

I've written a full guide for Ubuntu 20.04 on [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1351527/).